# "Noisy Image" connector is missing in compositing?

Tags: compositing-nodes, denoise, noise-reduction

When I tried to denoise the image, following the tutorial. There is no "noisy image" connector in compositing. I've enabled the "denoising data".

Thanks for your advice in advance.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it exists anymore, just plug Image, Denoising Normal and Denoising Albedo into the Filter > Denoise and it should work?

Comment: @moonboots It exists, it is only appearing to get the noisy image if you enabled _Denoising_ in the _Render Properties_ - because then your image will always be already denoised after  finishing the render. If you have it disabled and only want to denoise after rendering in the _Compositor_, there is no need for a noisy image output because the default image output only provides a noisy image.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Oh OK I understand now. In what way would it be interesting to re-denoise? I guess one should either use the Render > Denoise or the Compositor denoise, no?

Comment: @moonboots The Render Denoise and Compositor Denoise can give different results - mainly because of the _Denoising Albedo_ and _Denoising Normal_ passes I guess - the composited denoising sometimes preserves details a little bit better. Apart from that, according to the Blender Documentation for version 2.92, the _Denoising Data_ is mainly for denoising animation and not needed for still images: [Passes > Data > Cycles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/render/layers/passes.html)

Comment: Denoising Data is useful for animation from what it says, but if we use the Compositor denoise, what would be the difference or usefulness of switching on or off the Render > Denoise?

Comment: As I said above, I guess the _Denoising Albedo_ and _Denoising Normal_ passes might be responsible for this that sometimes the composited denoising gives a clearer image losing less details then the Render > Denoise. I remember having a slight difference where some detail got blurred too much, so I switched to the compositor for denoising. But most of the times it was hardly recognizable. Now if you want to use Compositor Denoise, switching Render Denoise on does not make any sense at all, because double denoising slows down render times and in the worst case blurs the image even more.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Oh ok that's what I wanted to know, thanks  ;)

Answer (score 2):

It only appears if you have denoising at render time enabled in the render settings panel. If you don't have render-time denoising enabled, there wouldn't be any difference between "noisy image" and the main "image" pass, because you haven't done anything to the main pass.

So just use the main "image" output on your Render Layers node, it's the same thing in this case.